# Indentation width in command mode

Tags: vim

I use Vim 7.3 on Windows 7 and have the following settings in my vimrc:

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
```

If I use **Tab** in 'insert mode' or **>>** in 'command mode' my text 
is indented by 4 spaces. 
But if I use **>>** in 'colon command mode' (I don't know if it's really 
called like that), for example with a range

```
:30,35>>
```

the text is still indented by 8 spaces.

What is the right setting to change this to 4 spaces?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you're indenting twice silly. `:30,35>`

Comment: please stop upvoting my answer. this question should be closed.

Comment: What's the reason for this? Are there other Ex commands that you can "multiply?"